# In Blazor, how do I implement client-side authorization checks that need server access?

Tags: authorization, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor client (i.e. wasm) app that uses resource-based authorization. I connect to a DB to authorize authenticated users. It is easy to implement the API-side authorization (e.g. via an authorization service). It is not easy to implement client-side authorization checks in the UI, because they require communication with the server.

Microsoft suggests using [an authorization service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#procedural-logic) imperatively. I have two questions about this usage:

1. What am I allowed/supposed to put in the authorization handlers behind this example? I can't use the same handlers I use for API authorization (e.g. I can't connect to a DB) because it's the client app. Is this example only for authorization that doesn't require talking with the server?
2. Since this solution is imperative rather than declarative, is it incompatible with `AuthorizeView`?

Comment: I feel flummoxed by this question because this *seems* like a use case that isn't uncommon, but I found nothing specifically about the need for server access. All the questions and answers are about how to "wire" auth checks. So I think I'm missing something on a conceptual level.

Comment: There's some...fundamental gap in my knowledge here. How is everyone making these auth checks?

Comment: I don't understand how seemingly everyone is able to use such simple auth policies that don't need a database.

Comment: Have you managed to solve this issue? One way I can think of is to actually have a client http dependency. So your policy / resource handler will use it to make a call to an api and that api can do the database stuff etc. Thoughts?