# Blazor webassembly resource-based policy with database lookup?

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

In my blazor webassembly project  (with asp.net core hosted), I am trying to create a policy-based authorization that does a database lookup.

**Questions**

1. Where should I be storing these policies, in the project solution? **Shared project**?
2. The only project that has knowledge of the dbcontext is the **Server project**. The **Shared project** doesn't have a reference to the **Server project**. So I'm trying to work out how to access this **DbContext** and how the **Client project** will be able to register the dependency injection for the **DbContext**?

**Idea**

I'm thinking that my policy would have to make a http request to an apicontroller in order to get the data, therefore leaving the database dependency injection in the server project.
Would this be the right way to go about?

**A similar question was asked here:**

[In Blazor, how do I implement client-side authorization checks that need server access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66259394/in-blazor-how-do-i-implement-client-side-authorization-checks-that-need-server)

[How can I use resource-based authorization client-side in Blazor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66260908/how-can-i-use-resource-based-authorization-client-side-in-blazor)

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you answered your question correctly. Keep your db context in the Server project. Shared project does know nothing about db and it should stay like that. If you want some data, retrieve them from db in Server project, convert them to DTOs and send them as an API response to your client (like you suggested). Store your DTOs in Shared project. Note that everything in the Shared project is sent to user as a part of the Client project.

You can get inspiration from: https://github.com/CuriousDrive/BlazingChat
or https://github.com/dotnet-presentations/blazor-workshop

Comment: Thank you for confirming my idea much appreciated